# NSPredicate in Swift, array of custom objects returning [CustomArray] does not have a member named 'filteredArrayUsingPredicate"

Tags: ios, swift, nspredicate

I have a function which filters an array based on dates.  I send the function an array called Spending Data.  This is an array of custom objects containing user's spending data (time, amount, etc).  I am getting the error "[SpendingData] does not have a member named 'filteredArrayUsingPredicate'.    This doesn't make sense to me, it is an array.  Any help would be appreciated.  I can get around this by sending the function a type of NSArray and returning NSArray, but this causes all kinds of errors when I try to use this new array (dataToView) in the tableView.

```
 func predicateStuff(spendingDataAll:[SpendingData])->[SpendingData]{          //Send in current array of spending Data dataModel.spendingDataDisplay (array)
        let searchPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "dateSpent >= %@ && dateSpent< %@",weekStart!,weekEnd!)
        var dataToView = spendingDataAll.filteredArrayUsingPredicate(searchPredicate!)
        return dataToView
    }
```

Comment: What version of Swift are you using? 1.2?

Comment: If you want to use a Swift Array, then you need to use native Swift functions. Use filter: instead of the NSArray method filteredArrayUsingPredicate:.